# Howto: Reference numbered elements of a list by their number

Tags: asciidoctor

I'd like to do something like this:

```
These are the problems:

1. Too much concrete
2. Too few plants

... 
This was also stated in Problem 1 and Problem 2.
```

The "Problem 1" and "Problem 2" should be links to the list above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Output

[image]

## syntax

These are the problems:

```
. [[prob1, Problem {counter:prob}]] Too much concrete
. [[prob2, Problem {counter:prob}]] Too few plants

This was also stated in <<prob1>> and <<prob2>>.
```

## Explanation

- `prob1` and `prob2` are IDs for the problems. You can freely choose them. E.g. `prob_concrete` and `prob_plants`. That way they would be easier to use.
- `{counter:prob}` is the syntax for counting the counter called `prob`. You can freely choose the countername. ([See "Counters" of the documentation](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#counters))
- `Problem {counter:prob}`: This is the part, that defines, how the reference is shown, when used (see image above).